# Кодировка в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, кодировка

Здравствуйте. Казалось бы проблема тривиальная до безобразия, но пролистав несколько форумов, я так и не нашел внятного чёткого решения.

В БД хранятся данные на русском языке. При попытке вывести их на экран получаю "?????????".
**В каком месте может быть проблема?**
Сразу добавлю:
-кодировка сайта utf-8
-кодировка файлов скриптов utf-8 без BOM
-кодировка таблиц utf-8 (сравнение utf8_general_ci)

При разработке везде старался ставить utf-8. Но всё равно наткнулся на данную проблему. 
При чём на локальном сервере работает всё без проблем. При переносе на реальный хостинг -  "?????" вместо русских символов.

Ещё есть один момент. Если данные добавлять в БД из скрипта, то они заносятся тоже кракозябрами - "´Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð²".

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Похоже исходная кодировка cp1252?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При соединении с базой попробуйте что нибудь одно

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

или

```
SET CHARACTER SET cp1251_koi8
```

ну или свое впиши, там где кодировка через черточку _ (cp1251_koi8) это значит будет преобразовываться из одной кодировки в другую

Comment: Хм, так всё просто оказалось. Спасибо огромное. Помогло - SET CHARACTER SET utf8.

Answer (score 3):

До всяких запросов (я ставлю сразу после подключения к БД):

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Это для MySQLi, ну а для MySQL там можно переправить в соответствии с документацией.